# Unable to set the height of a prototype cell as a constraint in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

How does one add a constraint for the height of a prototype cell using a storyboard?

In the first screenshot below, I used the storyboard's "Reset to Selected Constraints" to automatically set them based on the canvas. I tried it both at the view controller level and also at the view level(s). But the result was the same in every case - it only added the few constraints as can be seen in the screenshot and when the code is run the blue cell displays with a height which is the same as the red one).

[image]

If I now try to add an additional explicit constraint for the height of the cells it won't let me - the option is greyed out.

If I delete all the constraints and try and add them manually, the option to add them is still disabled - why is that? See screenshot below for an example.
Instead of selecting the headerCall as in the screenshot if I instead select Content View to set the constraints its the same, i.e. ability set them is disabled.

I'm just trying to add prototype cells where one type represents a section header which is narrow and another type represents a data content cell which is wider, but code's not making it obvious why I can't. (I don't have similar issues setting constrains with any of the other view controllers/views, just these prototype cells).

There is no code in the view controller setting any heights or constraints etc. Its virtually empty, I created it just to recreate the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually constraints shouldn't be applied directly to content view of UITableViewCell as they already act as dynamic wrapper and adjust their height according to their subviews.

Try adding a subview to content view and set a height constraint to that subview.  And at the same time pin all sides of your new subview to content view.

If you expect a static height from cell, then please override below code and make your viewController implement UITableViewDelegate:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat
```

Or if you want your cell height to be calculated from height constraints you just applied to subview of content view, in that case use:

```
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: For this to work on iOS 11/XCode 9.3, I had to set the height of the subview and centre it vertically. Pinning the top and bottom to the Content View rather than centring didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can't set the constraints for the UITableViewCell. Only way to set the constraints in programmatically. You can write the

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    //...
 }
```

In here you can give two heights for different rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set constraints to your cell. You can set constraints to it's contentView. And set Height of cell from size Inspector. If You want Dynamic size for your cell then you can use

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0; 
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

But You must use autolayout for that. Hope this will help You. :)